# Parse out space separated rows

Tags: awk, grep

I want to parse space separated rows. Text is something like this:

```
Record: 123456 xyz-1.1.1
     Item       Date
     abc        05-DEC-14
     ijk        05-DEC-14

Record: 987654 abc-2.2.2
     Item       Date
     xyz        06-DEC-14
     bcd        06-DEC-14

Record: 567890  stu-3.3.3
     Item       Date
     rst        04-DEC-14
     mno        04-DEC-14
```

I need to display a Record number and the Items below it. How can i do it?

Expected output is to extract one of the above Record # with its Items. I want to extract it on the basis of app name which for above examples are "xyz", "abc" and "stu". For e.g.

```
Record: 987654 abc-2.2.2
         Item       Date
         xyz        06-DEC-14
         bcd        06-DEC-14
```

Comment: show us the expect output.

Comment: What do you mean by `extract one of the above record` ? Did you want the record number `987654` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/ abc-/' RS=
```

Output

```
Record: 987654 abc-2.2.2
     Item       Date
     xyz        06-DEC-14
     bcd        06-DEC-14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v app="abc" '$1 ~ " "app"-"' file
Record: 987654 abc-2.2.2
     Item       Date
     xyz        06-DEC-14
     bcd        06-DEC-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you expect ?

```
$ awk '$1=="Record:"{printf "%s ", $2}$1=="Item"{print $2}' file
123456 Date
987654 Date
567890 Date
```

Answer (score 0):

That's better, here is what you need.

Set key with different value, and you will get the result.

```
key="987654"
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";key="'$key'"}{split($1,a,OFS);if (key==a[2]) print}'  infile

Record: 987654 abc-2.2.2
     Item       Date
     xyz        06-DEC-14
     bcd        06-DEC-14

key="123456"
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";key="'$key'"}{split($1,a,OFS);if (key==a[2]) print}'  infile

Record: 123456 xyz-1.1.1
     Item       Date
     abc        05-DEC-14
     ijk        05-DEC-14
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using sed:**

```
sed -n -r '/Record.*xyz/,/^$/p' File
```

(Similarly for abc & stu)

**Example:**

```
# cat File
Record: 123456 xyz-1.1.1
     Item       Date
     abc        05-DEC-14
     ijk        05-DEC-14

Record: 987654 abc-2.2.2
     Item       Date
     xyz        06-DEC-14
     bcd        06-DEC-14

Record: 567890  stu-3.3.3
     Item       Date
     rst        04-DEC-14
     mno        04-DEC-14
[root@CFPU-0(RNC-91) /root/umwdma_mt]
# sed -n -r '/Record.*abc/,/^$/p' File
Record: 987654 abc-2.2.2
     Item       Date
     xyz        06-DEC-14
     bcd        06-DEC-14

[root@CFPU-0(RNC-91) /root/umwdma_mt]
# sed -n -r '/Record.*xyz/,/^$/p' File
Record: 123456 xyz-1.1.1
     Item       Date
     abc        05-DEC-14
     ijk        05-DEC-14

[root@CFPU-0(RNC-91) /root/umwdma_mt]
# sed -n -r '/Record.*stu/,/^$/p' File
Record: 567890  stu-3.3.3
     Item       Date
     rst        04-DEC-14
     mno        04-DEC-14
```

**Logic:**

print from line containing "Record" and the pattern "abc" or "stu" or "xyz" till empty line.